# Increasing VM Performance on EC2 Bare Metal Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I recently created a bare metal (i3.metal) EC2 instance that I'm going to use as a farm for VMs (the guest VMs will be used for testing various cases). Because performance of the guest VMs is important, the specs of this EC2 instance are quite high: 72 vCPUs, 512GB RAM, 25,000 provisioned SSD iOPS. The host OS is Windows Server 2016.

On the guest VMs themselves, I've given each 16 CPUs (2 processors with 8 cores each) and 16GB RAM. All VMs are VMWare WorkStation v17.

However, performance of the VMs is dismal. Even with just a single VM running, from power on to Windows login screen prompt takes close to 10 minutes. These are essentially vanilla Windows 10 VMs so I would expect the power on to take closer to 60 seconds. I'm open to any suggestions on how I can get higher-performing VMs in this setup.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you use them for testing, do you do this 24/7? If not, may it not be cheaper to pay AWS only for a 16vcpu instance during the time you need it?

Comment: Curious why you need a large fast EBS volume when you have 16TB of very fast SSD storage? Backing up data, sure, but you probably don't need io1 for that.

Comment: By default after build I had an OS volume that was 860GB. I checked Disk Management and found 8 uninitialized 1.7TB volumes. I initialized one and moved one of my VMs to it and ran another startup test - unfortunately no change in performance.

Comment: Seeing interesting behavior now - if I lower the specs of the guest VMs to 4 vCPUs and 8GB RAM (from 16 vCPUs and 16GB RAM previously), the VMs start much more quickly (2ish minutes). However, they are immediately pegged at 100% CPU post-login.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are making any bare metal to host machine for vm's you have to tune it. To do so you need **tuned-adm** command if you want to execute predefine tunning, however still you need to fix some more stuff for production ready or to create test bed.
Hope it will help you.